# IntersectionObserver undefined for Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, intersection-observer

I have an IntersectionObserver to lazy load images etc., where `el` is the HTML Element and `offset` a number.

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  if (entries[0].isIntersecting === true) {
    el.srcset = this.image;
    observer.unobserve(el);
  }
}, {threshold: [0], rootMargin: this.offset + 'px'});

observer.observe(el);
```

**This observer works fine on every browser, but not on IE11.** Debugging it get the following error returned:

> "Intersection Observer" is undefined

Which makes the images not load at all. Is there a solution for IE? Since I suppose it's not supported on IE, but shouldn't the normal behavior be to execute the observer's code initially then?

Answer (score 3):

`IntersectionObserver` is not supported by IE. You could refer to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver#Browser_compatibility). If you want to support it in IE, you could use [this polyfill](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill). This library polyfills the native `IntersectionObserver` API in unsupporting browsers.

Answer (score 0):

IntersectionObserver is not supported in InternetExplorer.
You can refer to the below link for you reference.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#Browser_compatibility